# How to use postman?

Tags: magento2, postman

I use Magento 2.In Magento 2 Api are present.

How to use postman for a request like GET    /V1/modules.

Answer (score 15):

First you need to set up a user to get the authorization key. [This tutorial walks you through that process](https://inviqa.com/blog/magento-2-tutorial-overview-web-api). Once you have that, you can set up postman with these settings:

[image]

[image]

Where your GET request will have your URL (local or what not), and the `Bearer` will have your Access Token from the user you set up.

[image]

Also, you can test this out and get some information about the API from Swagger, the built in API UI. Every 2.2 install has access with this URL:

> http://magento222.local/swagger

You can place the same Access Token in `api_key` box and get access to all the APIs in the system (without the key you will only see public API endpoints).

[image]

Comment: Please note that as of 2.4.5, the setting `oauth/consumer/enable_integration_as_bearer` needs to be enabled for this to work. [Details](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also import all magento endpoints,
just follow this [article](https://medium.com/@yvoronoy/how-to-generate-schema-for-magento2-api-and-import-to-postman-c08a0318af98)

[image]